# How to define Enums in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design, model, ef-code-first

I have concerns around whether I am storing the enums value correctly? In my EventModel class I am storing them as int Id's.

I would also appreciate if you can think of a better database design? Anything I should change etc?

EventModel:

```
public class EventModel
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Title { get; set; }

public string Location { get; set; }

public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

public byte[] EventLogo { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

public int EventTypeId { get; set; }

public int EventTopicId { get; set; }
}
```

Ticket:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public int Quantity { get; set; }

public decimal Price { get; set; }

public bool Free { get; set; }
}
```

EventType Enum:

```
public enum EventType
{
    AppearanceOrSinging = 1,
    Attraction = 2,
    Conference = 3,
    Gaming = 4,
    Dinner = 5,
    FestivalOrFair = 6,
    SocialAndNetworking = 7,
    Competition = 8,
    Tour = 9, 
    Race = 10,
    SeminarOrTalk = 12,
    Workshop = 13,
    Other = 99
}
```

EventTopic Enum:

```
public enum EventTopic
{
    BusinessAndProfessional = 1,
    Sporting = 2,
    CharityAndCause = 3,
    Music = 4,
    TravelAndOutdoor = 5,
    FashionAndBeauty = 6,
    ReligionAndSpirituality = 7,
    Education = 8,
    FoodAndDrinks = 9,
    CommunityAndCulture = 10,
    ComputingAndTechnology = 11,
    Other = 99
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is supporting enums directly since version 5. You can simply replace your properties definition as follows:

```
public EventType EventType { get; set; }

public EventTopic EventTopic { get; set; }
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx)

Comment: And how is that gonna struct the database table? What the type will be against these columns?

Comment: By default, that would be `int`.